# How to access HTML element when I use module css

Tags: javascript, dom, css-modules

I am doing styling using module css and I wonder how I can access to an element with `document.querySelector`. It seems when I use module css, classname of an element is hashed so I can not access to the element by simply using `document.querySelector('.some-classname')`. I am not using any framework here so I can not use `useRef`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When selecting an element by classNames you are getting an array of the elements even if the class name is only used one time.

**Gives you the array of elements:**

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
```

**If you only have one element with this class you can style it like this:**

```
elements[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

Comment: If you use module css, you can't apply this method because className is hashed (randomized).